# many to many to many SQL schemas

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables: `A` and `B`.

A many-to-many relation units them through a join table `A_B`.

Now, my needs evolve: an `A` and a `B` can be related by *more than 1* way.

I don't know what is the more conventional way to do that.

Must I declare a new "relation_way" table that contains the different "ways" for a `A` to be connected to a `B` and use this to compose a ternary key in `A_B`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would simply add a column to `a_b` that states the type of the relationship, e.g. `relation_type` that stores e.g. `owned_by` or `referred_to` or however you want to describe that relation (your obfuscated table and column names do not help a bit in answering this).

```
create table a_b 
(
   a_id integer not null references a,
   b_id integer not null references b, 
   relation_type text not null
);
```

If you allow multiple relations but with different types between two entities, then include the relation_type in the primary key of the `a_b` table.

If you want to restrict the possible relation types, you should create a lookup table:

```
create table relation_type 
(
  id integer primary key, 
  type_name varchar(20) not null unique
);
```

and reference that from the link table:

```
create table a_b 
(
   a_id integer not null references a,
   b_id integer not null references b, 
   relation_type_id integer not null references relation_type, 
   primary key (a_id, b_id, relation_type_id)
);
```